# Where does Intellisense look for options for the Brush property in XAML editing?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, intellisense

In a WPF application, if i want to create a rectangle, i start to write this in the XAML:

```
<Rectangle Fill=
```

After i input the last `=` character, the Intellisense of Visual Studio will give me a bunch of options for this `Fill` property, such as AliceBlue, AntiqueWhite, and so on. I've found out that these constants come from class `Brushes`, but constants defined in my own class wouldn't be contained in the list of options for that property. So i have two questions.

1. property `Fill` is of type `Brush`. Type `Brush` is an ordinary type, and is not a enum type. How does Intellisense look for options for such a property?
2. Is it possible for Intellisense to consider objects defined outside the core assembly of WPF as options for a certain property?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The intellisense pulls from `System.Windows.Media.Brushes` which are just a couple default `SolidColorBrush` values.  You can use any Brush type though, like `LinearGradientBrush`, `RadialGradientBrush`, or `ImageBrush`.  If you want to define your own colors you can use a color's hexadecimal value (e.g., #FFFF0000, for aRGB values 255 opacity, 255 red, 0 green, 0 blue), or you can define resources in XAML and references them with `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource` (if you intend for this value to be changed at runtime).

Intellisense uses reflection to find variables, methods, functions. That list of colors comes from this class, which looks like this:

```
public sealed class Brushes {
    public static SolidColorBrush AliceBlue {
        get {
            return KnownColors.SolidColorBrushFromUint(-984833);
        }
    }

    public static SolidColorBrush AntiqueWhite {
        get {
            return KnownColors.SolidColorBrushFromUint(-332841);
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure exactly what you're asking in the second question, but it will only provide what's directly relevant with the given assemblies.  If you can clarify that question, please do.

Comment: Yes, i know these color literals come from class `Brushes`. What i want to ask is where does Intellisense search for `Brush` instances? Does it search for them within the namespace where class `Brush` is defined, or within the whole wpf core assemblies, or within my projects(which may contain references to other assemblies) ?

Answer (score 0):

Intelisense is showing you the list so because of those Definition here
          `xs:attribute` `name="Fill" type="StringToBrushConverter"/`

Behold the deffinition of StringToBrushConverter

```
name="StringToBrushConverter">
    pattern value="AliceBlue|AntiqueWhite|Aqua|Aquamarine|Azure|Beige|Bisque|Black|BlanchedAlmond|Blue|BlueViolet|Brown|BurlyWood|CadetBlue|Chartreuse|Chocolate|Coral|CornflowerBlue|Cornsilk|Crimson|Cyan|DarkBlue|DarkCyan|DarkGoldenrod|DarkGray|DarkGreen|DarkKhaki|DarkMagenta|DarkOliveGreen|DarkOrange|DarkOrchid|DarkRed|DarkSalmon|DarkSeaGreen|DarkSlateBlue|DarkSlateGray|DarkTurquoise|DarkViolet|DeepPink|DeepSkyBlue|DimGray|DodgerBlue|Firebrick|FloralWhite|ForestGreen|Fuchsia|Gainsboro|GhostWhite|Gold|Goldenrod|Gray|Green|GreenYellow|Honeydew|HotPink|IndianRed|Indigo|Ivory|Khaki|Lavender|LavenderBlush|LawnGreen|LemonChiffon|LightBlue|LightCoral|LightCyan|LightGoldenrodYellow|LightGray|LightGreen|LightPink|LightSalmon|LightSeaGreen|LightSkyBlue|LightSlateGray|LightSteelBlue|LightYellow|Lime|LimeGreen|Linen|Magenta|Maroon|MediumAquamarine|MediumBlue|MediumOrchid|MediumPurple|MediumSeaGreen|MediumSlateBlue|MediumSpringGreen|MediumTurquoise|MediumVioletRed|MidnightBlue|MintCream|MistyRose|Moccasin|NavajoWhite|Navy|OldLace|Olive|OliveDrab|Orange|OrangeRed|Orchid|PaleGoldenrod|PaleGreen|PaleTurquoise|PaleVioletRed|PapayaWhip|PeachPuff|Peru|Pink|Plum|PowderBlue|Purple|Red|RosyBrown|RoyalBlue|SaddleBrown|Salmon|SandyBrown|SeaGreen|SeaShell|Sienna|Silver|SkyBlue|SlateBlue|SlateGray|Snow|SpringGreen|SteelBlue|Tan|Teal|Thistle|Tomato|Transparent|Turquoise|Violet|Wheat|White|WhiteSmoke|Yellow|YellowGreen"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Everything is taken from WPFe schemma localized in : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas